# Interrogating DevOps Services REST API efficiently

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I've written a powershell script to count how many comments each developer has written on pull requests that weren't their own. In a nutshell the script is

```
get list of pull requests
for (every pull request) 
  get list of threads
  for (every thread) 
    get list of comments
    for (every comment where commentType = text)
      get comment
```

This will be pretty chatty in network terms and took some time to run. Is there a more efficient way to access this information?

Comment: I doubt it. I also would question the usefulness of this information as a metric.

Comment: I suspected that one guy was rubber stamping pull requests, he was

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of calls you can make?

Comment: No. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more efficient way to access this information?

For this issue , I am afraid there is no more effective way to achieve this demand. There is currently no out-of-the-box method, what I can think of is the same as you: first filter the pull request, then [get the comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20threads/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples) associated with threads according to the pull request id, and then retrieve the comments. Although this requires many api calls.

In addition, you could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.